# Delegete in table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, cell

I have a table on which a `cell` is made using `.xib`. There are two `view`s on this `cell`. When I click on each `view`, and I set the *image* and *title* for another `viewController`. I made a `protocol` for this, but I just can’t get this data on another `viewController` because my `delegate = nil`.

In this class, I set properties.

```
сlass DataTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var dataDelegete: DataAccountCellDelegete? = nil

 @objc func accountViewTaped() {
        dataDelegete?.navigationBarIcon(image: UIImage(named: "icon") ?? UIImage())
        dataDelegete?.navigationBarTitle(title: "title")
        
        
    }
    @objc func settingsViewTaped() {
        dataDelegete?.navigationBarIcon(image: UIImage(named: "icon") ?? UIImage())
        dataDelegete?.navigationBarTitle(title: "title")
    }
    
}
protocol DataAccountCellDelegete {
    func navigationBarIcon(image: UIImage)
    func navigationBarTitle(title: String)

}
```

In this class, I get and want to set these properties, but my `delegate = nil`

```
class AccountViewController: UIViewController {

var dataVC =  DataTableViewCell()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
       dataVC.delegete = self   
    }
}
extension AccountViewController: DataAccountCellDelegete{
    func menuNavigationBarIcon(image: UIImage) {
      menuNavigationBar.addImage(image)
    }
    
    func menuNavigationBarTitle(title: String) {
        menuNavigationBar.addTitle(title)
    }
}
```

> How do I declare a delegate correctly?

Comment: Cells are reused and being created in `cellForRowAt`. The variable `dataVC` is useless. A light-weight *swifty* way is to use callback closures in the cell.

Comment: why are you using cell ? do you have tableView ?

Comment: Yes, I use this cell in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view hierarchy should be like

```
ViewController -> TableView -> TableViewCell
```

So, ViewController has the reference of TableView & TableView has the reference of the cell. So the data passing should be reversed.

```
TableViewCell -> TableView -> ViewController
```

as [vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5044042/vadian) said ,Cells are reused and being created in cellForRowAt. The variable dataVC is useless here.